# How to make a loop while still executing the rest of the project

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Is there a way to implement a while loop that will keep going while the rest of the code will execute without stopping the while loop

```
while (true) {
   executeFunction(thatNeedsToKeepGoing);
}

moreCodeThat = needsToExecuteAt(theSameTime);
```

Comment: maybe you can use setInterval for that.

Comment: [What is the real problem you're trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Because you *can* create such a loop but it's very likely going to be a *bad idea*.

Comment: what about moving that code to an web worker?

Comment: @Ifaruki might work. Hence why we need the real problem in order to provide a real solution.

Comment: @VLAZ yea. its hard to find an solution with 4 lines of code question

Answer (score 0):

Method:

1. Use `setInterval`:

```js
setInterval(()=>{executeFunction(thatNeedsToKeepGoing)}, 100);
```

This will run the function every 100 milliseconds.